# the equivalent of a javascript code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, equivalence

I would like to know what is the equivalent of the javascript code below in PHP:

```
setTimeout ( "doSomething()", 5000 );
function doSomething ( )
{
    document.write('hello');
    setTimeout ( "doSomething()", 5000 );
}
```

Is there anyone who has any idea?

Comment: What do you intend it to do in PHP? PHP is executed on the server.

Comment: The bigger question is "what are you trying to do"? Generally PHP is called once to render a page. You might have better luck using JavaScript code with `setTimeout` to request additional PHP content at a later time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `header("Refresh: 5"); die("hello");` is the equivalent of the code you posted.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: in fact I would to know how to run a php code periodically , I tried to embed a PHP code inside a javascript code (you can have a look at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653452/an-embedded-php-code-inside-a-javascript-code-doesnt-work) ) but unfortunately it doesn't work, so I decided to try to find an equivalent of that code in PHP.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: please have a look at the comment just above .. the answer of your question "what are you trying to do?" is there.

Comment: @CheNadim the solution to that is to use JavaScript to call `setInterval()`, which in turn makes an AJAX call to your PHP script. So it isn't PHP executing periodically, it is JavaScript making a periodic AJAX call _to the PHP_.

Comment: @CheNadim - As Michael says, you would not "run PHP code periodically" to affect a change on the client, since PHP runs on the server. Instead you need to have the client make periodic server (PHP) requests.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: well can you tell me how can I make a periodic AJAX call to the PHP code??...Just will give you me a simple example no more??...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: well, can you tell me how to make the client make a periodic server PHP requests??...then will you give me just a simple example if it is possible??..Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest using AJAX with jQuery. The code is straightforward...

Comment: But you should do some research. The topic is larger than a comment or code snippet.

Comment: @CheNadim Start here: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ The `setTimeout()` doesn't change, but inside it, execute a jQuery AJAX call to `yourscript.php` whose responsibility is to `echo` some output. You then trap the response (as documented in the jQuery examples) and do something with it via JavaScript (like modify an element in your DOM)

Answer (score 9):

The PHP `sleep()` function would stop the script for some time. Check it out there:

https://www.php.net/sleep

The code you posted in PHP should be:

```
sleep(5);
doSomething();

function doSomething( )
{
   echo 'hello';
   sleep(5);
   doSomething();
}
```

But I don't really see the point of doing that kind of thing on the server side.

Comment: I think , this is also helpful http://www.php.net/manual/en/ev.examples.php

Comment: The only issue with this is that you can't removeTimeout. I'd add some sort of flag that could be checked to see if the "doSomething" method should be called. But you are right... there doesn't appear to be much call for doing this on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, in fact we just need more information from Mr. CheNadim! Your need is the key ;)

Comment: "But I don't really see the point of doing that kind of thing on the server side." Totally agree with you !

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA - This might answer the immediate question, but it seems like a major design problem... for example, do you really want to wait an extra 5 seconds for a page to load? This will only be the case in extreme circumstances, such as throttling invalid login attempts as mentioned on PHP.net.

Comment: @Justin Ethier - +1000, just waiting for the author to tell us WHY he actually want to do this ^^

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA: in fact I would to know how to run a php code periodically , I tried to embed a PHP code inside a javascript code (you can have a look at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653452/an-embedded-php-code-inside-a-javascript-code-doesnt-work) ) but unfortunately it doesn't work, so I decided to try to find an equivalent of that code in PHP. By the way, I put the code that you post in your answer but it displays on the screen this error message:"FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". Do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: @CheNadim - Yeah, take a look at the `set_time_limit`function here http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php , it will allow you to increase the maximum execution time of your PHP script.

Comment: @CheNadim - However, I still don't understand what you really want to do on your page. Executing a PHP code periodically is possible, but it answers needs completely different from the ones the original JS script does. What do you want to achieve on your page exactly?

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA: in fact, I want to execute the PHP code below periodically:

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jqcalendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "a new event was added";
}
?>

Do you have any idea how to do that??..if that is not possible, is there any other technologies to use??...then will you give me just a simple example??..Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CheNadim - Ok, well, I guess you should do researches about Ajax. This is the technology you want to user here I think. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

As PiTiNiNjA stated, you can use the 'sleep()' method in PHP, but I must ask why you intend on doing this.

PHP, unlike Javascript is executed on the server, the client machine never sees it.

The delay in the PHP file will cause a delay from request to response, leaving the user on a blank page while they wait out the delay.

If you want a client to continually poll a PHP script, you should look into AJAX, which is Javascript making additional requests at runtime.

Comment: in fact I would to know how to run a php code periodically , I tried to embed a PHP code inside a javascript code (you can have a look at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653452/an-embedded-php-code-inside-a-javascript-code-doesnt-work) ) but unfortunately it doesn't work, so I decided to try to find an equivalent of that code in PHP. By the way, do you have any idea about how to run this php code periodically: <?php echo "hello"; ?> . Then can you give me just a simple example about how to do that using AJAX ?..Thanks in advance.